# Powershell switch in custom function

Tags: powershell, parameters

The `Get-ChildItem` Cmdlet has a `-Recurse` switch.

How can we call it passing the switch in our own custom functions?

```
function Get-Files {
    [OutputType([int])]
    param(
        [string]$Path,
        [string]$Filter,
        [switch]$Recurse,
        [int]$DaysBackModified,
        [int]$DaysBackCreated
    )

    if ($Recurse) {
        return Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Filter -Recurse
    } else {
        return Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Filter
    }

}
```

Is it possible to avoid the `if`?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the switch is present in the [`$PSBoundParameters`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) hashtable. Cast the result to bool to account for an omitted switch. Then pass it to the `-Recurse` switch of `Get-ChildItem`.

```
return Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Filter -Recurse:([bool]$PSBoundParameters.Recurse.IsPresent)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, found this:

```
return Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Filter -Recurse:$Recurse
```